# Do Tarski's Axioms prove all of Euclid's Elements?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry, axioms, incompleteness

A fairly self explanatory title; do Tarski's first order axioms given in his famous 'What is Elementary Geometry?' Suffice to prove all of the theorems in Euclid's Elements? (Excluded non-plane geometric theorems).

Now, Euclid spends a considerable amount of time using geometry to develop number theory systematically, including the theory of primes and the like. Tarski proved his axioms complete, but if his axioms suffice for all Euclidean geometry, how does this not contradict Godel's incompleteness theorem since a theory that contains number theory is certainly strong enough for Godel incompleteness to appy?

Comment: See [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) : they are relative to "elementary" space geometry: no numbers. "Tarski proves that Euclidean geometry is *decidable*: there exists an algorithm which can determine the truth or falsity of any sentence. Tarski's axiomatization is also *complete*. This does not contradict Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, because Tarski's theory lacks the expressive power needed to interpret Robinson arithmetic."

Comment: This means that we have **not** to confuse "sufficient for Euclidean geometry" with "sufficient for all theorems of Euclid's *Elements*".

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't really address whether or not Tarski's axioms are 'sufficient for all theorems of Euclid's Elements'.

Comment: They are **not**. They cannot express e.g. [Book VII and on](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html) regarding *number theory*. There are no "primitives" for *unit* and *number*, not the def of *prime nuber, odd, even*, etc.

Comment: You can see the beautiful : Ian Mueller, [Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid’s Elements](https://books.google.it/books?id=0MDDAgAAQBAJ) (1981, MIT Press). In **Ch.2 Euclidean Arithmetic** the arithmetic of Book VII is analyzed : "Because of the independence of these books the modern reader is somewhat surprised to find no specifically arithmetic postulates in the *Elements*." Mueller's reconstruction list all specific arithmetical assumptions needed to prove the arithmetical theorems of Book VII.

Comment: @ElieBergman *Vollstandigkeit* (as Hilbert called it, *completeness*) is only formalizable in second order logic. No contradiction with Gödel’s theorem which deals with first order theories.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , I see now. But do Tarski's axiom cover all of the purely geometric aspects of Euclid, i.e. curcumscribing triangles, constructing regular pentagons, bisecting angles and the like?

Comment: Maybe useful : Alfred Tarski & Steven Givant, [Tarski's System of Geometry](https://www.jstor.org/stable/421089), BullSL (1999).

Comment: See also William Richter, [Tarski Geometry Axioms](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/forma.2014.22.issue-2/forma-2014-0017/forma-2014-0017.xml) (2014).